# I have a text file loaded in a JTable, i want that the changes i make in the JTable to be made in in the text file as well, how can i do that?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

```
String[] columns = {"nume", "compozitie", "indicatii", "contraindicatii", "administrare", "pret", "compensabil"};

Object[][] data = null;
try {
    File file = new File("medicamente.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("medicamente.txt"));
    int lines = 0;
    while (reader.readLine() != null) {
        lines++;
    }
    reader.close();
    data = new Object[lines][];
    String line;
    int numLines = 0;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        data[numLines] = line.split(",");
        numLines++;
    }
    fileReader.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns) {
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        Class returnValue;
        if ((column >= 0) && (column < getColumnCount())) {
            returnValue = getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        } else {
            returnValue = Object.class;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
};

JTable table = new JTable(model) {
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 5:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
};

final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 500));
mainPanel.add(scrollPane);
scrollPane.setBounds(0, 240, 995, 510);
```

as you can see i made one of the columns editable, the others are not. I read somewhere that the only solution is to clear the text file and than load the modified JTable in the text file. what would be the best option here ?

Answer (score 0):

`I read somewhere that the only solution is to clear the text file and than load the modified JTable in the text file.`

Given that you are storing the data in a text file, that is correct.

You may want to check out [Table Cell Listener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/). It tells you when data has changed in a cell. Then you can invoke your code to recreate the text file.

If you don't want to use this class then you can also use a TableModelListener for this purpose. Read the link for the difference between the two approaches.

Comment: could you help me with this? how to do so that when the JTable is loaded in the text file again, between the content of every cell to be placed a comma ? because when the text file is loaded, the "," is used as a separator for every cell content

Comment: @user3307020, You create a nested loop, one for ever row in the table and then one for every column in the row. For each column you use the table.getValueAt(...) method to get the value and write the value to a file. Then you write out ",". When you finish writing all the columns you write out the new line string.

Comment: so i create a "for" for rows and inside the first "for" i create another for the columns, i get that, but i still don't get the rewriting thing. and also i get an error when trying to use a tablecelllistener